# Unable to check JSON response condition to show data in tableview cell in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, switch-statement

this is json response in postman:

```
{
"result": {
 
    "categories": [
        {
            "title": "ADMINISTRATION & SECRETARIAL",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 266,
                    "certificate_required": "Y",
                    "get_service": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "BUILDING",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 299,
                    "certificate_required": "Y",
                    "get_service": {
                        "id": 778,
                        "get_certificate": {
                           
                            "certificate_file": "62e3a911d0233.jpg",
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 148,
            "title": "DIGITAL DEVELOPMENT ",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 152,
                    "title": "WEB DESIGN",
                    "certificate_required": "N",
                    "get_service": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

here i need to check `get_certificate` is there or not

so i have written code like below:

here if

```
get_certificate != nil
```

then i need to show

```
cell.subCatLbl.text = "\(indexData?.title ?? "") (Uploaded)
```

but still showing

```
cell.subCatLbl.text = "\(indexData?.title ?? "") (Certificate).
```

why?

where am i wrong. please guide me

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return categoryData[section].children?.count ?? 0
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddserviceCell", for: indexPath) as! AddserviceCell
cell.selectionStyle = .none

let indexData = categoryData[indexPath.section].children?[indexPath.row]

switch indexData {
case _ where indexData?.certificate_required == "Y":
    cell.subCatLbl.text = "\(indexData?.title ?? "") (Certificate)"
case _ where ((indexData?.get_service?.get_certificate) != nil):
    cell.subCatLbl.text = "\(indexData?.title ?? "") (Uploaded)"
default:
    cell.subCatLbl.text = indexData?.title
    break
}
return cell
}
```

Comment: There is no `certificate_required` in your json so we have no idea why your code isn't working.

Comment: If the `children` are directly related to the value in `title` it might be easier to `switch` on `title` or even decode the stuff into an enum with associated values. And there are too many question marks in the code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, json response fully added.. please check

Comment: I agree with @vadian, there are too many question marks. Perhaps start with `if let indexData = ...`

Comment: @vadian, how to `switch` title.. please let me know

Comment: Never mind the data is not related to the `title` value. In the first two records `certificate_required` is “Y” so you get *Certificate*. For the third record you get the `default` case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not achieving the outcome you expect because of your switch statement.

The switch statement execute only one of its paths, the first matching condition to be precise. So every time

```
indexData?.certificate_required == "Y"
```

is true

```
cell.subCatLbl.text = "\(indexData?.title ?? "") (Certificate)"
```

will execute regardless of what comes next.

Solution:

Either resort the switch condition so that the condition with the highest priority comes first:

```
case _ where ((indexData?.get_service?.get_certificate) != nil):
    cell.subCatLbl.text = "\(indexData?.title ?? "") (Uploaded)"
case _ where indexData?.certificate_required == "Y":
    cell.subCatLbl.text = "\(indexData?.title ?? "") (Certificate)"
default:
    cell.subCatLbl.text = indexData?.title
    break
```

or use an if/else approach here:

```
if indexData?.get_service?.get_certificate != nil && indexData?.certificate_required == "Y"{
    cell.subCatLbl.text = "\(indexData?.title ?? "") (Uploaded)"
} else if indexData?.certificate_required == "Y"{
    cell.subCatLbl.text = "\(indexData?.title ?? "") (Certificate)"
} else {
    cell.subCatLbl.text = indexData?.title
}
```